# Not able to PUT multiple users to https://api.vimeo.com/channels/{channel_id}/privacy/users

Tags: vimeo

In reading https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/channels#PUT/channels/{channel_id}/privacy/users it looks like it should be possible to allow multiple users to view a private channel by sending a body with multiple users.

When I issue the following cURL

```
curl -X PUT \
https://api.vimeo.com/channels/1407898/privacy/users \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {bearer token}' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-H 'Postman-Token: 8a5288c3-1352-4c90-8874-aa622930c4e7' \
-d users=89969174
```

I get back

```
{
    "error": "Something strange occurred. Please try again.",
    "link": null,
    "developer_message": "The body of this HTTP request is not formatted properly. Please check the content-type header and raw body.",
    "error_code": 2205
}
```

I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong, here?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/channels#PUT/channels/%7Bchannel_id%7D/privacy/users) on that endpoint is a bit lacking - Vimeo will [fix that soon](https://github.com/vimeo/mill/issues/195).

To add multiple users, you'll need to send an array of objects:

```
curl -X PUT 
  https://api.vimeo.com/channels/*channel_id*/privacy/users 
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
  -H 'Authorization: bearer *token*' 
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
  -d '[
        {"uri":"/users/*userid1*"},{"uri":"/users/*userid2*"}
    ]

'
```